# Keycloak query to count users filtered by custom attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to implement a user management system using Keycloak 16.0. I need to filter and display users by custom attribute in different pages. In order to achieve that, I need a query to count the users for the pagination functionality, and another query to fetch the users per page.

Keycloak supports filtering by custom attribute using a query similar to the following example:

```
{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users?first=5&max=10&q=attribute:value
```

But I can't find a way for the `users/count` endpoint to support such filtering. So my question is, is there a way to filter by attribute using the `/count` endpoint in order to implement the pagination correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. But there is on open issue for that: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14648

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on this issue 