# Keycloak API count users by their custom attribute

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to be able to get a total count of users having a specific attribute in order to make my pagination work.

`GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users/count`

As per [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.2/rest-api/index.html), the only parameter that could help me is `search` but I'm not sure if I can provide custom fields or attribute, i.e `?q=customAttr:36900000`. It seems that it only works for some fields like `username`, `email`

Is there any way to filter count API by other fields?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296555/keycloak-query-to-count-users-filtered-by-custom-attribute?rq=2 answer not really